# Call the method of base Class which was over ridden

Tags: java, inheritance

I have illustrated my question in this example

```
class Car {
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Started!!!");
    }
}

class Mercedes extends Car {
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Mercedes Started!!!");
    }
}
```

Now, in my main program, I write

```
Mercedes m = new Mercedes();
m.start();
```

It prints: *Mercedes Started!!!*

How do I call the `start()` method of `Car` class using the same object so that the output can be

*Car Started!!!*.

**Edit**:

> Actually It was asked in an interview I attended. I gave the *super* keyword answer. But the interviewer denied it. He said he'd give me a hint and said Virtual Function. I have no idea how to use that hint.

Comment: Virtual function? In Java, all non-static methods are, by default, virtual functions unless they are `final` or `private` (or package private as an edge case.)

Comment: I guess the interviewer try to trick me to find how I handle such situations

Comment: A virtual function is a function whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature and I guess most of the solutions are using this property.

Answer (score 3):

Your method should either call the super implementation like.

```
public void start(){
    super.start();
    System.out.println("Mercedes Started!!!");
}
```

or it doesn't. In which case you are saying that you have replaced the parent's implementation.

Though its not a good idea, you can work around this by adding a method.

```
public void startCar(){
    super.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method has been *overridden* in the subclass, so it's effectively replacing the method on the superclass.

The subclass itself can call the method in the superclass:

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
  public void startFromCar() {
    super.start();
  }
  public void start(){
    System.out.println("Mercedes Started!!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah
Is there no way to invoke the overridden method?

Comment: Can I not call the overridden method without altering the definition of the subclass

Comment: Actually It was asked in an interview I attended.
I gave the answer which u gave. But the interviewer denied it.
He said he'd give me a hint and said *Virtual Function*. I have no idea how to use that hint

Answer (score 1):

keyword `super`

```
class Car {
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Started!!!");
    }
}
class Mercedes extends Car {
    public void start(){
        super.start();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
class Car {
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Started!!!");
    }
}
class Mercedes extends Car {
}
```

now if you call `new Mercedes().start();`, "Car Started!!!" is printed.

Comment: In which case, you can delete the Mercedes.start() method ;)

Comment: I want to call the overridden method without altering the definition of the subclass

Comment: Abhijith Venkata: then only subclass it and let polymorphism do the right thing

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add another method to the `Mercedes` class to call the superclass's `start` method:

```
public void superStart() { super.start(); }
```

The `super` keyword allows you to access the class from which you are inheriting (the superclass). More about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten the method of the Parent class in your child class.
To access such methods [`super`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword is used.

so changing

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
public void start(){
    System.out.println("Mercedes Started!!!");
}

}
```

to

```
class Mercedes extends Car {
public void start(){
    super.start();
    System.out.println("Mercedes Started!!!");
}

}
```

will print

```
Car Started!!!
Mercedes Started!!!
```

or if you want to access is separately without altering the given function, try defining a new method in `Mercedes` class.

```
public void startCar(){
    super.start();
}
```

Calling this function will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option

```
class Car {
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Started!!!");
    }
 }
 Class Mercedes extends Car {
    //nothing here
 }
```

then the call

```
Mercedes m = new Mercedes();
m.start();
```

will print:

> car started!!!

if you want to have an object similar to Mercedes at print something else instead car started!!!
It should look like this

```
    class AlfaRomeo extends Car {.
        @override
        public void start(){
        System.out.println("Car Started!!!");  
        System.out.println("Its AlfaRomeo!!!");
        }
    }
```

@override telld java use childs method not parents.

```
AlfaRomeo a = new AlfaRomeo();
 a.start();
```

so the print will be:

> car started!!!
>
> Its AlfaRomeo!!!